# converting mysqli to to codeigniter syntax

Tags: codeigniter, mysqli

Good day! I am trying to convert the mysql syntax to codeigniter working with ajax but my head is aching to solve this problem maybe because i'm new in codigniter,.. here is my code

in my model

employee-grid-data.php

```
 <?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "test";
 $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or   die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 $requestData= $_REQUEST;
 $columns = array( 
 0 =>'employee_name', 
 1 => 'employee_salary',
 2=> 'employee_age',
 3 => 'id',
 );
 $sql = "SELECT id, employee_name, employee_salary, employee_age ";
 $sql.=" FROM employee";
 $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get      employees");
  $totalData = mysqli_num_rows($query);
 $totalFiltered = $totalData; 
 $sql = "SELECT id, employee_name, employee_salary, employee_age ";
 $sql.=" FROM employee WHERE 1=1";
 if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {  
 $sql.=" AND ( employee_name LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";    
 $sql.=" OR employee_salary LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
 $sql.=" OR employee_age LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' )";
 }
 $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get  employees");
 $totalFiltered = mysqli_num_rows($query);
 $sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   "; 
 $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get   employees");
 $data = array();
 while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array
 $nestedData=array(); 
 $nestedData[] = $row["id"];
 $nestedData[] = $row["employee_name"];
 $nestedData[] = $row["employee_salary"];
 $nestedData[] = $row["employee_age"];
 $data[] = $nestedData;
 }
 $json_data = array(
        "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),
        "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  // total number of  records
         "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), // total number of  records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
         "data"            => $data   // total data array
         );
 echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format
 ?>
```

and here is my view
index.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <title>Datatable</title>
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js">  </script>
     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"  src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/table.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var dataTable = $('#employee-grid').DataTable( {
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax":{
                    url :"employee-grid-data.php", // json datasource
                    type: "post",  // method  , by default get
                    error: function(){  // error handling
                        $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
                        $("#employee-grid").append('<tbody class="employee- grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
                        $("#employee- grid_processing").css("display","none");

                    }
                }
            } );
        } );
     </script>
     <style>
        div.container {
            margin: 0 auto;
            max-width:760px;
        }
        div.header {
            margin: 100px auto;
            line-height:30px;
            max-width:760px;
        }
        body {
            background: #f7f7f7;
            color: #333;
            font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica  Neue",HelveticaNeue,Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
        }
     </style>
 </head>
 <body>
     <div class="header"><h1>DataTable</h1></div>
    <div class="container">
        <table style="color:black;" class="rwd-table" id="employee-grid"   cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Employee name</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                        <th>Age</th>


                    </tr>
                </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

here is the syntax that what I'm trying to change to my model area.

```
// getting total number records without any search
$this->db->select('id, employee_name, employee_salary, employee_age');
$this->db->from('employee');
```

I removed the database connection syntax and apply to the config/database.php but wont work at all.

Comment: `employee-grid-data.php` does not look at all like a CodeIgniter Model file. If you removed the native PHP database calls please edit the question to show exactly what you have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of information you need here: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html

If you haven't gone through the tutorials, you can find them here: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html

They're very helpful to figure out the basics.

`config/database.php`

```
 $db['default'] = array(
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'test',
    ...
);
```

`model`  I'll call it `employee_model`. `models/employee_model.php`

```
class Employee_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
            $this->load->database();  // or autoload it...
    }

    public function get_employee_grid() 
    {
        $result = StdClass();

        //$requestData= $_REQUEST;  
        // use $this->input->post('id') for POST Data
        // use $this->input->get('id') for GET Data
        // etc...

       $q = $this->db->select("id, employee_name, employee_salary, employee_age")->get('employee');
       $result->count = $q->num_rows();  //get's number of rows
       $result->rows = $q->result();   // object of resulting rows

    ...
       // when you need to search... use ->where()
       $this->db->$this->db->select("id, employee_name, employee_salary, employee_age")->where('id', $this->input->post('id'))->get('employee');

       return json_encode($result);
    }
```

From your view, `url :"http://example.com/your_controller/employee_grid_data",`

call the controller:

```
class Your_controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function employee_grid_data()
    {
        $this->load->model('employee_model');

        $data = $this->employee_model->get_employee_grid();

        // if you expect ONLY JSON data, you can echo
        echo $data;

        // otherwise, you pass the variable to the view
    }
}
```

Hopefully this puts you on the right path...